# Google App Script error 404: Response not defined

Tags: post, google-apps-script, google-sheets, response, urlfetch

My code is supposed to get some data from google sheet and POST to a system via external API.I, however, keep running into the error 404 when I run the code.

On debug, it indicates that **response** is not defined. Here is the potion of the code with the issue. Am I missing something?

```
function postLeave(){
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();  
  // used getLastRow() function [1] to narrow the array to have only cells with data.
var range = sheet.getRange("K2:K"+sheet.getLastRow()).getValues();
var searchString = "";


for (var i = 0; i<range.length; i++) {
    if(range[i][0] == searchString) {
    var lastRow = sheet.getRange(2+i,1,1,10).getValues();
    var userid = sheet.getRange("I2:I" + sheet.getLastRow()).getValues();


    var data = {
        //'user_id': lastRow[0][8],
        "leave_type_id":lastRow[0][9],
        "date":lastRow[0][7],
        "hours":lastRow[0][6],
 };
      var payload = JSON.stringify(data);
      var options = {
        'method': 'POST',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'payload' : data,
      };
      var url = 'https://api.10000ft.com/api/v1/users/' + userid + '/time_entries?auth=key;
      var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText();
      if (response === 200) {
      //var json = JSON.parse(response);         
      sheet.getRange(2+i, 11).setValue(1); 
      }
    else {
     sheet.getRange(2+i, 11).setValue(0);

     Logger.log(response)

    }
 }
}
}
```

Documentation

[image]

Challenge with endpoints.

https://github.com/10Kft/10kft-api/blob/master/sections/assignables.md

https://github.com/10Kft/10kft-api/blob/master/sections/leave-types.md
https://github.com/10Kft/10kft-api/blob/master/sections/time-entries.md

Comment: Possibly the line `'payload' : data,` should be `'payload' : payload,`, since you want to pass the stringified value?

Comment: Can you provide the official document of the method of the API that you want to use?

Comment: @Tanaike please find it in this link https://github.com/10Kft/10kft-api/blob/master/sections/time-entries.md

Comment: @AaronDuniganAtLee, I have tried that but still run into the same error

Comment: Thank you for replying. When I saw the document of Creating Time Entries of the link, `project_id` is not used. But `data` in your script has the property of `project_id`. And also, it seems that the endpoint is different between your script and the document. And in your script, although `api/v1/users` is used, `user_id` is not used and `project_id` is used. So I cannot understand what method in the API you want to use. Can I ask you about these?

Comment: Hey, @Tanaike much appreciated on looking into this. I actually wanted to get leave days from the G-sheet and post to 10k ft. Ideally, I need to post hours, days & leave types, but I am even finding that to be a challenge too, as am not sure how to structure the URL. I have tried to use time assignable endpoint but still unable to POST

Comment: Thank you for replying. For "Time Entries", there are 2 endpoints which are `/api/v1/users/<user_id>/time_entries` and `/api/v1/projects/<project_id>/time_entries`. In your case, I think that at first, it is required to decide the endpoint you want to use. By this, the structure of the form-data can be prepared. But from your question and replying, I cannot understand about what you need. So how about clarifying your direction?

Comment: I am trying to get leave type, date and hours posted via the API. The screenshot in my edited question showed that this is possible with time entries endpoint. Unfortunately, I have not been able to make this work as there is more confusion in the links in my edited question. Many thanks

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your updated question, I proposed 2 sample scripts. Could you please confirm it? Unfortunately, I cannot test above scripts. I apologize for this. So if this didn't resolve your issue, I apologize. At that time, please provide the error message and the script for replicating the issue. Of course, please remove your personal information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this modification?

#### Modification points:

- `Content-Type` cannot be directly used to the option of `UrlFetchApp.fetch()`.
- `var payload = JSON.stringify(data);` is not used.
- `options` is not used at `var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText();`. In this case, it requests to the URL with the GET method.
- `var url = 'https://api.10000ft.com/api/v1/users/' + userid + '/time_entries?auth=key;` is not enclosed by `'`.

Unfortunately, from the official document, I couldn't understand if it is required to send this data in json data or form data. So I proposed following 2 patterns. Please check them.

#### Modified script 1:

In this modified script, the data is sent as json data. Please set each variables. And also please set `key`.

From:

```
var payload = JSON.stringify(data);
var options = {
  'method': 'POST',
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  'payload' : data,
};
var url = 'https://api.10000ft.com/api/v1/users/' + userid + '/time_entries?auth=key;
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText();
```

To:

```
var payload = JSON.stringify(data);
var options = {
  'method': 'POST',
  'contentType': 'application/json',
  'payload' : payload,
};
var key = "###"; // <--- Please set your key.
var url = 'https://api.10000ft.com/api/v1/users/' + userid + '/time_entries?auth=' + encodeURIComponent(key);
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options).getContentText();
```

#### Modified script 2:

In this modified script, the data is sent as form data. Please set each variables. And also please set `key`.

From:

```
var payload = JSON.stringify(data);
var options = {
  'method': 'POST',
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  'payload' : data,
};
var url = 'https://api.10000ft.com/api/v1/users/' + userid + '/time_entries?auth=key;
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText();
```

To:

```
var options = {
  'method': 'POST',
  'payload' : data,
};
var key = "###"; // <--- Please set your key.
var url = 'https://api.10000ft.com/api/v1/users/' + userid + '/time_entries?auth=' + encodeURIComponent(key);
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options).getContentText();
```

#### Note:

- In above modified scripts, it supposes that each value in `data` object and `key` are correct.

#### Reference:

- [Class UrlFetchApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app)

Comment: Thanks, @Tanaike, I really appreciate the assistance. I used modified script 2: works great.

Comment: @Just Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.